# How to find data length and index length of particular tables in a postgresql schema?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am migrating my application from MySQL to PostgreSQL. In MySQL, I have used a query to calculate memory size of particular tables as per my requirement using the below Query,

```
SELECT SUM(ROUND(((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024),2)) 'Size in MB' FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME like 'table_name';
```

But I can't do the same in PostgreSQL. If I run the same query it is displaying as,

```
ERROR:  type "sum" does not exist
```

And I have tried the solutions in various sites but I can't find the exact solution for my requirement. Please suggest me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your query  query is failing because you're using single quotes for alias - `'Size in MB'`.

Further, there's no `DATA_LENGTH` and `INDEX_LENGTH` available in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

In Postgres, you may use `pg_total_relation_size` function.

```
SELECT ROUND(pg_total_relation_size (oid) / ( 1024.0 * 1024.0 ), 2) AS 
       "Size in MB" 
FROM   pg_class c 
WHERE  relname = 'table_name';
```

Have a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41991566/7998591) answer to know the  functions available to get various sizes.

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a384f79af70db0bfc929f8791a953417https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a384f79af70db0bfc929f8791a953417)

Comment: I have tried this query but the value differs when I compare it with mysql and postgresql.

Comment: @Kishore : I'm not sure how it works in MySQL, so can't comment about it.But,  I can assure you that the value returned is true for a Postgres table. Check the SO answer I've linked in my answer and you may find various sizes listed there. Replace it in the query and check if any of those closely match with the value you're expecting to see. Also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3490952/7998591) where it is described how the storage size could vary across MySQL and Postgres

Comment: What is that "oid" parameter represented in your query? @Kaushik Nayak

Comment: @Kishore : Read about [OIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5627085/7998591) and description of columns in [pg_class catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/catalog-pg-class.html)

Comment: Let me tell you an example, from that you can help me out with the values changed in postgres and mysql. Consider, there is a table with same structure and same no of rows in both postgres and mysql. If I try to calculate their size in respective environment, whether there is any possibility in value difference? Hope you can understand my example and situation. @Kaushik Nayak

Comment: @Kishore : If you carefully read the answer in the link in my previous comment, which makes the comparison, that is what it says: there could be difference simply because of the way the two databases store data. What's the amount of difference you're seeing by the way?

Comment: In mysql it is displaying as 0.06MB and in postgres 106KB. @Kaushik Nayak

Comment: @Kishore :  Ok. 60 KB and 106 KB is what it is. I can't really help you more on this as MySQL is not my expertise. You'll have to explore. I have answered based on what's mentioned in Postgres manual and I trust that it is a genuine result.

Comment: Thanks for giving your valuable suggestions. @Kaushik Nayak

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not have this information in **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES** but you can try using the table **SVV_TABLE_INFO** to get the table size instead.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nope! It just displays that there is no relation like svv_table_info. Any other suggestions please.