# How is Postgres table size GREATER than Mysql Table Size?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design, timescaledb

On comparing Mysql and Postgres table sizes we found that:

**Postgre Table size** (4758390 rows) (vanilla postgres): 1402MB

> Data Length = 1063MB
>   Index Length = 339MB

**Mysql Table Size** (4758390 rows) (with Inno DB): 1056MB

> Data Length = 845MB
>   Index Length = 211MB

The tables have the following schema:-
The schema:-
**MySQL**
int(11)
varchar(15)
datetime
float
float
float
float
float
double
double
double
float
longtext
double
double
int(11)
double
float
int(11)
int(11)
float
int(11)
int(11)
int(11)
int(11)
varchar(50)
int(11)
int(11)
int(11)

**Postgres**
serial
varchar
timestamp
double precision
double precision
double precision
double precision
double precision
numeric
numeric
numeric
double precision
varchar
numeric
numeric
double precision
numeric
double precision
integer
integer
double precision
integer
integer
integer
integer
varchar
integer
integer
integer

The query used to calculate the sizes for the tables are:-

MySQL

```
SELECT table_name AS `Table`,data_length, index_length,
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB`
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = "DB_NAME
      AND table_name = "TABLE_NAME";
```

Postgres

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('TABLE_NAME'));
```

Edit:-
**Indexes in MySQL:**        Size
(varchar(15),datetime) ->   133 MB
            (datetime) ->   78 MB
**Indexes in Postgres:**     Size
(varchar,timestamp)    ->   339 MB
I am new to databases and wondering how is this possible.

Comment: This question lacks the details necessary to answer it. Compare the table and the indexes. Look how the data is stored in the pages, Determine how many rows are stored in each page in both systems. Add relevant details to the question, then maybe someone can answer.

Comment: You don't show any effort researching how the tables are implemented.

Comment: myisam or inoodb ?

Comment: The engine is InnoDB.

Comment: Also, what other details do i need to add ?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can you please elaborate on how to determine the rows that are stored in each page?

Comment: On PostgreSQL, use the `pageinspect` extension to see details. the `ctid` of each row contains the block number, so that gives you a quick count or rows per block. Read all about the [database page layout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html).

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490050/postgresql-vs-mysql-how-do-their-data-sizes-compare-to-each-other i hope this will help you.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490050/postgresql-vs-mysql-how-do-their-data-sizes-compare-to-each-other i hope it will help you.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490050/postgresql-vs-mysql-how-do-their-data-sizes-compare-to-each-other *i hope this will help you*.

Comment: What is the average number of bytes in the LONGTEXT column?

Answer (score 4):

**You're using data types with different sizes:**

Mysql floats are 4 bytes vs postgresql doubles which are 8 bytes

Mysql datetime looks like 4 bytes (I was unable to find clear documentation) whereas postgreql timestamp is 8 bytes.

Mysql integer(11) is  4 bytes, while for Postgresql numeric *The actual storage requirement is two bytes for each group of four decimal digits, plus three to eight bytes overhead*

Comment: MySQL's `DATETIME` used to take 8 bytes; now it takes 5 bytes.  And, as a rule of thumb, InnoDB's overhead is 2x to 3x.